# How would I display a dynamic de/scaling SVG transformation in Javascript to the page?

Tags: javascript, svg, css-animations

I have an SVG with two circles that are animated using @keyframes. I want to display the value of the circle's growth. Using javascript I want to display the value as they shrink and grow. getTotalLength() is probably not what I should be using but am not sure of the name of what I am looking for that does size/value check.

[My codepen](https://codepen.io/tiffanylo/pen/vJgLOX)
[an example of how it would look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgdG7.png)

```js
//   console.log("DOM Ready!");
//   // setInterval, changes global var, translates the size of the val.
//   // ever second or two
//   // point 0.1 means 10px

//   // displaying each circle's value as they grow and shrink
//   var redValue = document.getElementById('red-grow').innerHTML = span;
//   // var greenValue = document.getElementById('green-grow').innerHTML =

//   var redCircle = document.getElementsByClassName('red');
//   var greenCircle = document.getElementsByClassName('green');
//   var current = 0;
//   var width = 0;
//   var destination = 700;
//   var friction = 0.04;

//   // scaling up both circles
//   function scaleUp() {
//     //  console.log(scaleUp);
//     current += (destination - current) * friction;
//     redCircle[0].style.width = (current * 0.5 + 'px');
//     greenCircle[0].style.width = (current * 0.5 + 'px');
//     if (current >= destination - 0.1) {
//       // clearInterval(redAnimate);
//     }
//   }
//   var redAnimate = setInterval(scaleUp, 20);

//   // scaling down both circles
//   function scaleDown() {
//     //console.log(redCircle[0].style, greenCircle[0].style);
//     current += (destination - current) * friction;
//     redCircle[0].style.width = (current * 0.5 + 'px');
//     greenCircle[0].style.width = (current * 0.5 + 'px');
//     if (current >= destination - 0.1) {
//       // clearInterval(greenAnimate);
//     }
//   }
//   var greenAnimate = setInterval(scaleDown, 20);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #584E56;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .3rems;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.red, .green {
  transform-origin: 60% 60%;
  -webkit-animation: zoom 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: zoom 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(0.7, 0.7);
  }
}

.timeline {}
```

```html
  <h1>Animation SVG</h1>

    <span class="" id="red-grow">
      <!-- display here the red circle's value when growing and shrinking -->
      Value:
    </span>
    <span class="" id="green-grow">
      <!-- display here the green circle's value when growing and shrinking -->
      Value:
    </span>
    <svg width="500" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill="none" d="M-1-1h502v302H-1z"/>
      <g>
        <path class="timeline" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4.5" stroke="#000" fill="none" d="M39.5 31.5v239M463.5 269.5l-422-1"/>
        <ellipse class="red" id="inner" stroke="#e5a3a3" ry="65.5" rx="67" cy="165" cx="158.5" stroke-width="4.5" fill="none"/>
        <ellipse class="green" stroke="#98FB98" ry="65.5" rx="67" cy="165" cx="361.5" stroke-width="4.5" fill="none"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: What exactly does "the value of the circle's growth" mean?  The radius, the area, the circumference?

Answer (score 0):

The current value of the animated `transform` property can be extracted using the `getComputedStyle()` method.  That returns a matrix in string form which then need to extract the scale value from.

Here's an example solution that displays the current scale as a percentage.

```js
var redCircle = document.getElementsByClassName('red')[0];
var greenCircle = document.getElementsByClassName('green')[0];

var redLabel = document.getElementById('red-grow');
var greenLabel = document.getElementById('green-grow');

function updateLabels()
{
  var transformValue = getComputedStyle(redCircle).getPropertyValue('transform');
  // transformValue is a string of the form "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0 ,0)".
  // For this example the first number in the matrix corresponds to the scale.
  // We'll use a regular expression to extract it.
  var currentScale = transformValue.match(/matrix\(([\d.]+)\,/)[1];

  redLabel.textContent = Math.round(currentScale * 100) + '%';

  requestAnimationFrame(updateLabels);
}

requestAnimationFrame(updateLabels);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #584E56;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .3rems;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.red, .green {
  transform-origin: 60% 60%;
  -webkit-animation: zoom 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: zoom 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(0.7, 0.7);
  }
}

.timeline {}
```

```html
<h1>Animation SVG</h1>

    <span class="" id="red-grow">
      <!-- display here the red circle's value when growing and shrinking -->
      Value:
    </span>
    <span class="" id="green-grow">
      <!-- display here the green circle's value when growing and shrinking -->
    </span>
    <svg width="500" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill="none" d="M-1-1h502v302H-1z"/>
      <g>
        <path class="timeline" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4.5" stroke="#000" fill="none" d="M39.5 31.5v239M463.5 269.5l-422-1"/>
        <ellipse class="red" id="inner" stroke="#e5a3a3" ry="65.5" rx="67" cy="165" cx="158.5" stroke-width="4.5" fill="none"/>
        <ellipse class="green" stroke="#98FB98" ry="65.5" rx="67" cy="165" cx="361.5" stroke-width="4.5" fill="none"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

However in my opinion, it might be more straightforward to avoid using CSS animation, and instead update the circle transform or radius yourself in the `requestAnimationFrame()` function.